# BEAMER commands don't work when exporting org-mode to beamer

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

I'm trying to produce a minimalistic presentation using `org-mode` and `beamer` latex.

But I keep getting a pdf file with only one frame, and "I think" commands starting with `BEAMER_` is not working.

Using the following code, I expect to have a presentation with 3 frames with `Madrid` theme. However, I get a one frame presentation with default beamer theme.

```
#+AUTHOR: Sameh
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2

** Frame 1
 some text here
*** headings 1
*** headings 2

** Frame 2
some text here
*** headings 1
*** headings 2

** Frame 3
some text here
*** headings 1
*** headings 2
```

If I change `#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid` to `#+latex_header: \mode<beamer>{\usetheme{Madrid}}`, the theme will work.

I "think" `#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2` and `#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid` are not recoginsed, and it maybe the thing causing the problem.

I need to know how to make `#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid` work? and how to make presentation provide multiple frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this happened because I was publishing to pdf using usual latex pdf using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, with small <kbd>p</kbd>, where it should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with capital <kbd>P</kbd> for beamer pdf publishing.